# Why is C=C launching electrophilic attack on Bromine instead of the other way round?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

So during my lecture on reaction of Alkenes with Halogens, my lecturer used the example of $\ce{Br2}$ gas reacting with $\ce{CH2CH2}$. He mentioned that the $\ce{C=C}$ launches an electrophilic attack on the electropositive Bromine atom (the one that is nearer to $\ce{CH2CH2}$) and I'm wondering why is the $\ce{C=C}$ launching the electrophilic attack? Shouldn't it be done by the Bromine gas since the $\delta^+ \ce{Br}$ is electrophilic and **needs** the electrons so it attacks the double bond which is most electron dense?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [help]. || Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation " latex ‎at ‎chemistry.se"), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/) on how to make your future posts better.‎ Alternatively, visit [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27198/latex-mathjax-help) for further formatting guidance.

Comment: That's seems wrong. The bromine molecule is the electrophile and the double bond is the nucleophile and I would normally describe it as an electrophilic attack by the bromine on the double bond.

Comment: If it just happened once, I am guessing it was a slip of the tongue by your lecturer, it happens... I have said much stupider stuff than that in my lessons :/ In any case, as bon said, $\ce{Br_2}$ is the electrophile and $\ce{C2H4}$ the nucleophile.